# bash while loop with ssh only last output displays

Tags: bash, ssh

I have server list in file and in a while loop I will read and runt he command using ssh. it displays only last server uptime output. other servers its not displaying.

eg:

```
cat a
host1
host2

cat a | while read s; do ssh -q $s -x "uptime"; done
```

it shows only host2 uptime output.

we changed to run like this it displays both servers output

```
cat a | while read s; do echo "ssh -q $s -x uptime"|bash; done
```

I like to understand, why we need while read loop displaying only last output.

Is anyother way we can execute the ssh remote command using while loop?

Thanks
SR

Comment: `ssh` is eating your standard input. Use the `-n` flag to prevent that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh breaks out of while-loop in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393038/ssh-breaks-out-of-while-loop-in-bash)

Comment: ssh with -n works, also  redirecting stdin to /dev/null works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
while read -r s
 do ssh -q $s -x "uptime" </dev/null
done < a
```

This is happening because `ssh` is trying to read from stdin