# run a script with $(cat filename.txt)

Tags: linux, shell, sh

So im running a script called backup.sh. It creates a backup of a site. Now I have a file called sites.txt that has a list if sites that I need to backup. i dont want to run the script for every site that I need to backup. So what im trying to do is run is like this:

```
backup.sh $(cat sites.txt)
```

But it only backups the 1st site thats on the list then stop. any suggestions how i could keep make it go throughout the whole list?

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over the lines of a file, use a `while` loop with the `read` command.

```
while IFS= read -r file_name; do
    backup.sh "$file_name"
done < sites.txt
```

Comment: Not sure but I think this could be done without the `IFS=` part?

Comment: @src Yeah, with a single argument I guess `IFS` never comes into play

Comment: There is another potential problem, though: If `backup.sh` consumes standard input, it will gobble up the data from `sites.txt` and probably put it somewhere completely in the wrong place.  You can prevent that with `backup.sh "$file_name" </dev/null` inside the loop.

Comment: Agree, OP did not mention multiple arguments inside `sites.txt`

Comment: @tripleee I'd instead redirect `sites` using a different file descriptor, since `backup.sh` presumably has a reason for reading from standard input. `while IFS= read -r file_name <&3; do ...; done <3 sites.txt`.

Comment: `IFS=` is necessary to preserve leading and trailing whitespace in a line; the fact that `read` has only a single argument prevents word-splitting.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that detail of `IFS`.  The redirection problem is a FAQ e.g. when a backup script uses `ssh` to connect to a remote host; the `ssh` session will usurp standard input even when you didn't mean it to.  The fix to redirect `ssh` to read from `/dev/null` is well documented.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393038/ssh-breaks-out-of-while-loop-in-bash

Comment: The interface to any program includes the file descriptors it will read from, so it's really a matter of knowing ahead of time which ones it is safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

The proper fix is to refactor `backup.sh` so that it meets your expectation to accept a list of sites on its command line.  If you are not allowed to change it, you can write a simple small wrapper script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for site in "$@"; do
    backup.sh "$site"
done
```

Save this as maybe `backup_sites`, do a `chmod +x`, and run it with the list of sites.  (I would perhaps recommend `xargs -a sites.txt` over `$(cat sites.txt)` but both should work if the contents are one token per line.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do, provided that sites.txt has one site per line (not tested):

```
xargs -L 1 backup.sh < sites.txt
```

If you are permitted to modify `backup.sh`, I would enhance it so that it accepts a list of sites, not a single one. Of course, if sites.txt, is very, **very** large, the `xargs` way would still be the better one (but then without the -L switch).