# Read file as input for a command skipping lines

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the contents of a text file as the input for a command. I know how to read a file just fine. However, when I pass the read line to the command I want to execute, the script starts skipping every other line.

Given a plain text file named `queue`:

```
one
two
three
four
```

This prints out each line as expected:

```
queue=`pwd`/queue
while read input; do
  echo $input
done < $queue
```

output:

```
one
two
three
four
```

However, when I pass `$input` off to the command, every other line is skipped:

```
queue=`pwd`/queue
while read input; do
  echo $input
  transcode-video --dry-run $input
done < $queue
```

output (transcode-video outputs a bunch of stuff, but I omitted that for brevity. I don't believe it is relevant):

```
one
three
```

I managed to get my script working by first reading the whole file into an array and then iterating over the array, but I still don't understand why directly looping over the file doesn't work. I'm assuming the file pointer is getting advanced somehow, but I *cannot* figure out why. `transcode-video` is a ruby gem. Is there something I'm not aware of going on behind the scenes when the ruby program is executed? The author of the gem provided a sample script that actually strips lines out of the file using a `sed` command, and that works fine.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9393038/258523) and its duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launched app tries to process stdin, and reads a line. Try:

```
transcode-video --dry-run $input </dev/null
```

Or check the manual for a command-line flag that does the job.

Comment: Holy crap. That's it! I assumed it would _use_ $input as the stdin input. Thanks!

Comment: @JordanBondo Command line arguments are not standard input. And it is quite possibly using the `$input` argument *and* reading standard input. Many commands do that.

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh right, der. I knew that (if I actually _bothered_ to take 2 seconds to think about it)