# Bash script rm command failed in while loop

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop, rm

I have a remote server with a couple of cache keys and I am trying to delete them. However, I am getting an error when I am running the script.

This is the script that I am using at the moment. Also, I setup public ssh key so I don't have to type the password:

```
input="path to file"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ssh  -tt user@192.168.20.59 "sudo -S rm $line"
done < "$input"
```

If I try the ssh command outside the loop will work as expected. I can't figure out why the loop affecting the command

The error that I am getting is:

```
No such file or directory3f971a5e192fb9332c764a636a4205f
connection to 192.168.20.59 closed.
```

Thank you in advance

NOTE:
Fixed the issue by modifying the script which generated the file. For some reason was adding ^M at the end of the line. I used echo & cat to generate the file and avoid alien characters

Comment: Is there really no space after the word "directory" in the error?

Comment: Not related to the error, but the loop will only process the first line of the file. Use the `-n` option to `ssh`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393038/ssh-breaks-out-of-while-loop-in-bash

Comment: How are you answering the `sudo` password prompt, since input is redirected from the file?

Comment: @andregr_jp: Picking up the first comment by Barmar: Could it be that `$input` contains carriage returns?

Comment: What if you do `ssh  -tt user@192.168.20.59 "sudo -S rm $line"` -> `ssh  -tt user@192.168.20.59 "sudo -S rm $line" </dev/null`

Comment: @Barmar, the loop process all the lines from the file and I am getting the same error for all the files. However I will try all the suggestions and will update you soon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script while read line loop stops after the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino That's a fix for a different problem, which the OP claims he's not having (but I don't know why). It's another duplicate of the one I linked to.

Comment: @Barmar But the solution must be the same, add `-n` to ssh command.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino How would that fix a "file not found" error?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by modifying the script which generated the file. For some reason was adding ^M at the end of the line. I used echo & cat to generate the file and avoid alien characters