# ssh to the machine and run the linux command using shell script and store it in the file

Tags: linux, shell

I have machines stored in host.txt file.
I need to read each line from file and do the ssh for it and run the linux command "cat /etc/redhat-release". Store the output along with machine name in the output file. Not sure if exit is also required after running ssh command.

**script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line do
    sshpass -p 'abc123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${line}
    echo `cat /etc/redhat-release` >> logfile.txt
done < host.txt
```

Above one is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r server; do
  sshpass -p 'abc123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" cat /etc/redhat-release <&-
done <host.txt >logfile.txt
```

or with GNU xargs with -P option with 10 processes:

```
xargs -P10 -d '\n' -i{} sshpass -p 'abc123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {} cat /etc/redhat-release <host.txt >logfile.txt
```

Research: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 [While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash) and [ssh breaks out of while-loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393038/ssh-breaks-out-of-while-loop-in-bash) https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting . Check your scripts with https://www.shellcheck.net/ .

Comment: Won't parallelism potentially intermix output?

Comment: Potentially it would, but `redhat-release` is one line and buffering is about lines, so it "works". `parallel` is better.