# Bash while loop from txt file?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, do-while

i trying to make a script to organize a pair of list i have, and process with other programs, but im a little bit stuck now.

I want from a List in Txt process every line first creating a folder to each line in the list and then process due to different scripts i have.

But my problem is is the list i give to the script is like 3-4 elements works great and create there own directory, but if i put a list with +1000 lines, then my script process only a few elements thru the scripts.

EDIT: the process are like 30-35 scripts, different language python,bash,python and golang

Any suggestions?

```
cat $STORES+NEW.txt | while read NEWSTORES 
do
    cd $STORES && mkdir $NEWSTORES && cd $NEWSTORES && mkdir .Files
    python3 checkstatus.py -n $NEWSTORES
    checkemployes $NEWSTORES -status
    storemanagers -s $NEWSTORES -o $NEWSTORES+managers.txt
    curl -s https://redacted.com/store?=$NEWSTORES | grep -vE "<|^[\*]*[\.]*$NEWSTORES" | sort -u | awk 'NF' > $NEWSTORES+site.txt
     ..
     ..
     ..
     ..
     ..
     ..
    cd ../..
done
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would only process the first few lines of the file.

Comment: Unless `checkstatus.py` or `checkemployes` tries to read from standard input. Then they'll read the rest of the input file.

Comment: Aside: You can create both directories at once with `mkdir -p "$NEWSTORES/.Files"`

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in your bash script?

Comment: @joop : Complementing the comment by _Barmar_: You have left out many commands from your loop body, and replaced them by just `..`. Did you verify that they don't eat your standard input?

Comment: @glennjackman Hello Glen, yes in one part of the script

Comment: With `set -e` any command that returns non-zero (with some caveats) will **cause the script to exit**. Long discussion about it at [bashfaq 105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Hello @glennjackman i understand, but the set -e is before the loop

Comment: Do you turn it off with `set +e` before entering the loop? If not perhaps you should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not supposed to give an answer yet but I mistakenly answered my what should be a comment reply.  Anyway here a few things I can suggest:

- Avoid unnecessary use of `cat`.
- Open your input file using another FD to prevent commands that read input inside the loop from eating the input: `IFS= read -ru 3 NEWSTORES; do ...; done 3< "$STORES+NEW.txt"` or `{ IFS= read -ru "$FD" NEWSTORES; do ...; done; } {FD}< "$STORES+NEW.txt"`.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28837793/445221.
- Not completely related but don't use while loop in a pipeline since it will execute in a subshell.  In the future if you try to alter a variable and expect it to be saved outside the loop, it won't.  You can use `lastpipe` to avoid it but it's unnecessary most of the time.
- Place your variable expansions around double quotes to prevent unwanted word splitting and filename expansion.
- Use `-r` option unless you want backslashes to escape characters.
- Specify `IFS=`  before read to prevent stripping of leading and trailing spaces.
- Using `readarray` or `mapfile` makes it more convenient: `readarray -t ALL_STORES_DATA < "$STORES+NEW.txt"; for NEWSTORES IN "${ALL_STORES_DATA[@]}"; do ...; done`
- Use lowercase characters on your variables when you don't use them in a global manner to avoid conflict with bash's variables.