# Bash: Sending data file into C program line by line

Tags: bash, unix

I have a question regarding sending data from a file line by line to a C program that will then convert the data's values from Fahrenheit to Kelvin. How do I read in the program line by line and then grab the output line by line back into my script?

Comment: So you have a file that has a list of temperatures, and you want to get the converted temperature for each one, so you can do something with each one?  If so, you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619438/bash-read-a-file-line-by-line-and-process-each-segment-as-parameters-to-other-p) for part of it

Comment: How does the C program read the data?

Comment: What is wrong with reading one line a time in the C program? I do not understand why you would want something like `while  read -r line; do cprog "${line}"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what is required here because the interface to the converter program is not specified.  Assuming that the program is called `f2k`, that it reads Fahrenheit values one-per-line from standard input and writes the converted values one-per-line to standard output, and that the file `fahrenheits.txt` contains a list of Fahrenheit values, one-per-line, this will put a newline-separated list of the Kelvin values into the `kelvins` variable:

```
kelvins=$(f2k <fahrenheits.txt)
```