# Shell script to execute command on each line of a file with space-delimited fields

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to write a shell script that reads a file line by line and executes a command with its arguments taken from the space-delimited fields of each line.

To be more precise, I need to download a file from an URL which is given in the second column to the path given in the first column using wget. But I don't know how to load this file and get the values in script.

**File.txt**

```
file-18.log https://example.com/temp/file-1.log
file-19.log https://example.com/temp/file-2.log
file-20.log https://example.com/temp/file-3.log
file-21.log https://example.com/temp/file-4.log
file-22.log https://example.com/temp/file-5.log
file-23.pdf https://example.com/temp/file-6.pdf
```

**Desired output is**

> wget url[1] -o url[0]

```
wget https://example.com/temp/file-1.log -o file-18.log
wget https://example.com/temp/file-2.log -o file-19.log
...
...
wget https://example.com/temp/file-6.pdf -o file-23.pdf
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: read a file line-by-line and process each segment as parameters to other prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619438/bash-read-a-file-line-by-line-and-process-each-segment-as-parameters-to-other-p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use read and a while loop in bash to iterate over the file line-by-line and call wget on each iteration:

```sh
while read -r NAME URL; do wget "$URL" -o "$NAME"; done < File.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning a file into arguments to a command is a job for `xargs`:

```sh
xargs -a File.txt -L1 wget -o
```

- `xargs -a File.txt`: Extract arguments from the `File.txt` file.
- `-L1`: Pass all arguments from 1 line to the command.
- `wget -o` Pass arguments to the `wget` command.

Comment: There may be issues with this approach if the address contains "&" and it needs quoting.

Comment: @RamanSailopal `xargs` has no issue passing URL argument with an `&` ampersand sign, tested and verified with this URL : `https://example.com/temp/file-1.log?foo=bar&baz=2+qux=corge`

Comment: It _does_, however, mangle literal backslashes and quotes and split on non-newline whitespace unless used with extensions such as `-d` or `-0`. Without `-d $'\n'` or `-0`, I'm very hesitant to recommend xargs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you have literal white-spaces unencoded backslashes and quotes in your URL, then you have encoding issues with: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438008/different-behaviours-of-treating-backslash-in-the-url-by-firefox-and-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can count, using a `for` loop and the output of `seq` like so:

In bash, you can add numbers using `$((C+3))`.

This will get you:

```sh
COUNT=6
OFFSET=18

for C in `seq "$((COUNT-1))"`; do
  wget https://example.com/temp/file-${C}.log -o file-$((C+OFFSET-1)).log
done

wget https://example.com/temp/file-${COUNT}.pdf -o file-$((COUNT+OFFSET-1)).pdf
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I misread your question. So if you have a file with the file mappings, you can use awk to get the URL and the FILE and then do the download:

```sh
cat File.txt | while read L; do
  URL="$(echo "${L}" | awk '{print $1}'"
  FILE="$(echo "${L}" | awk '{print $2}'"
  wget "${URL}" -o "${FILE}"
done
```

Comment: Using `awk` like this is much slower than just telling `read` to split the data into two variables itself.

Comment: `while read -r url file; do ...; done <file` -- note also the use of lower case variable names; upper-case ones are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself.

Comment: Similarly, `seq` is not part of bash itself _or_ part of the POSIX spec. Better to use `for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do ...`

Comment: :-) Wow, so much stuff. I hereby declare defeat. ;-) That file-trick is good, though. I didn't know about that one.

Comment: `done <file` is particularly important because of the issue discussed in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024); when you pipe to a `while read` loop, that pipeline is moved into a subshell, so variables it sets disappear when it exits.